# read file contents and send as json object in Apigee

Tags: apigee

I have a url which downloads a file containing json data.
I want to expose a url in apigee which will return a json response containing the contents of the files . Please let me knw how its possible to do so?

Please note that the file location url is something like https://someurl/Config_test.JSON which on clicking downloads a file.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simple proxy configuration within Apigee. Essentially you would map a proxy request URL to a target URL - adding whatever additional policies you would require (threat protection, rate limiting, authorization controls, etc).

Have a look at https://pages.apigee.com/learn-create-and-manage-apis-registration.html - we offer an eLearning course which will guide you through the steps required to do exactly what you mention.

Comment: Hi David, When i am creating a proxy over this url and hit the proxy url ,its just downloading that file. The url downloads a file ,a txt file . I need to read the data in file  and construct a response .

Comment: In that case you would "intercept" the content in the response flow and mediate the content. This can be done with standard XML policies or with a call out to a JavaScript, Python, or Java processor.